# Is it possible to perform $lookup on the previous $lookup stage without unwinding?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 documents that are structured like this: (I add some annotation to highlight what data I am using for the different lookup stages)

```
Client {
  _id,
  companyId -> initial match
}

Project {
  _id,
  clientId, -> stage 1 lookup (client._id)
  createdBy
}

User {
  _id, -> stage 2 lookup (project.createdBy)
  firstName,
  lastName
}
```

I have an aggregate pipeline setup like this that returns an array of clients with an array of projects for each client.

```
Client.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      companyId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.companyId)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'projects',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'clientId',
      as: 'projects'
    }
  },
])
.sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```

Now within the projects array is an object of the project key/values and I want to do another $lookup to get user information based off the createdBy field. I made a few attempts at solutions while reading through the aggregation pipeline docs and wasn't able to come to a working solution. One issue I'm having is that I'm not able to $unwind the first lookup as I need an array of projects. I think it would be possible if my projects were unwinded and looked something like this:

```
projects: {
  "projectId": {
    ...project
  }
}
```

But that's not currently how things are. Is there a way to accomplish this with lookup stages? My desired output is this:

```
clients: [
  {
    _id: 0,
    projects: [
      {
        _id: 0,
        createdBy: {
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Doe"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
]

// ideal 2nd stage lookup
{
  lookup: {
    from 'users',
    localField: 'projects.project.createdBy',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'createdBy'
  }
},
{ $unwind: '$createdBy' }
```

Comment: #mongoabuse, #relational

Comment: @barrypicker true.. time to migrate to postgres

Comment: Changing technologies to match your strategy is one approach.  Another approach is change the strategy to match the technology.  There are pros and cons to each.